# Use google's autocomplete service to search (and output) only country and/or city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I initialise google places api as follows:

```html
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&types=cities"
    ></script>
```

and in my code, I bootstrap the service as follows:

```js
const autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input }, predictions => {
 console.log(predictions);
});

autocomplete.getPlacePredictions('London');
```

I'd expect the query to only return a set of cities matching that query, but instead it returns a list of London based addresses.

How could I make it return only city results matching that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `types` property cannot be added to the Maps API script itself. You need to add it to your request to `AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions` as follows:

```
autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input: 'London', types : ['(cities)'] }, predictions => {
    console.log(predictions);
});
```

Maps JS API script (without `types`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Output:

```
London, UK
London, ON, Canada
London, KY, USA
Londonderry, UK
London, OH, USA
```

For reference check out the resources below:
[AutocompletionRequest interface reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest)
[Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)

Hope this helps!